# Sharepoint 2013 Have any position or page to view the setting logs of document library or list Library

Tags: document-library, site-collection, library

In Sharepoint 2013,

there are any position or page to view the setting logs of  document library or list Library?

For example, certain admin is modified the title or setting such as create versioning. there have any log to store who and when to modified the title and setting.

since the site collection is granted most of admin to maintain the Pages, unfortunately, we doubt one of admin is modified the page document setting(disabled versioning or etc.)

thank you very much.
i searched, but still no any idea.

Comment: not sure but did you check Audit Reports are enabled ? does this give you any data about settings change...I am sure it gives data about modification to items in list...

Comment: item is alright that is a versioning control by library setting but here no any log for store user config setting

Answer (score -1):

Yes , In SharePoint 2013 we have a option under **Site Administration** called **Popularity Trends** which will show the usage of the whole site in individual user basis

[image]

This option will generate a excel file **Popularity Trends**, shows usage event statistics for a site collection, a site, or an individual item in a library or list. Hope this will help you to track the changes has been made to library or a list.

Please refer https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715890.aspx for more info on this.

Comment: but this report only know the usage of the site that is not a log to store the behavior of user. let say, 15:30 user1 changed the libraryA certain setting